# How do I construct SQL with Left Joins (Oracle) between 2 tables, when the actual value I want is a referece in the 2nd table to a third table?

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have difficulties describing the issue in a searchable way (google):

I am creating a view based on more or less Left joins to multiple tables. The original table (left) is filled with foreign keys that I need replaced with the values. I do this with Left joining the referenced tables. However, a few of these left join tables only give me another foreign key, which I then need to sub query to get the value I want.
I bet there is an easy answer, but my googlefu is not worthy.

Example:

[Table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lz0j.png)

Extract from the View SQL (removed bulk)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_EQ_HISTORY (
id,
tag,
original_wo,
wo_status,
wo_task_code,
wo_task_name,
(etc)...
)
AS
SELECT
a.wmm_eqhist_id id,
b.wmt_tag_name tag,
c.wmm_wo_code original_wo,
c.elc_status_id wo_status,
d.wmm_wotask_id wo_taske_code,
d.wmm_wotask_id wo_task_name,
(etc)...

FROM WMM_EQUIPHISTORY a
LEFT JOIN wmt_tag b ON (a.wmt_tag_id = b.wmt_tag_id)
LEFT JOIN wmm_workorder c ON (a.wmm_wo_id = c.wmm_wo_id)
LEFT JOIN wmm_woitem d ON (a.wmm_woitem_id = d.wmm_woitem_id)
(etc)...
WHERE a.wmm_eqhist_createddate >= To_Date ('01/JAN/2013','dd/mon/yyyy') 
WITH READ ONLY
 CONSTRAINT vw_eq_history
/

GRANT SELECT ON vw_eq_history TO pbiuser;
```

The wo_status column gets the elc_status_id from wmm_workorder, but I want the name/description from the elc_statuses table to replace the elc_status_id my view.

I attempted a subquery '(Select...) as wo_status' but had to give in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a *-to-one correlation from  `wmm_workorder` to `elc_statuses` then include it as a `JOIN`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_EQ_HISTORY (
  id,
  tag,
  original_wo,
  wo_status,
  wo_task_code,
  wo_task_name,
  (etc)...
)
AS
SELECT a.wmm_eqhist_id,
       b.wmt_tag_name,
       c.wmm_wo_code,
       s.name_or_description,
       d.wmm_wotask_id,
       d.wmm_wotask_id,
       (etc)...
FROM   WMM_EQUIPHISTORY a
       LEFT JOIN wmt_tag b ON (a.wmt_tag_id = b.wmt_tag_id)
       LEFT JOIN wmm_workorder c ON (a.wmm_wo_id = c.wmm_wo_id)
       LEFT JOIN elc_statuses s ON (c.elc_status_id = s.elc_status_id)
       LEFT JOIN wmm_woitem d ON (a.wmm_woitem_id = d.wmm_woitem_id)
       (etc)...
WHERE  a.wmm_eqhist_createddate >= DATE '2023-01-01'
WITH READ ONLY
 CONSTRAINT vw_eq_history
/
```

or, specifying it as an `INNER JOIN` and using brackets to set the precedence of the `JOIN`s:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_EQ_HISTORY (
  id,
  tag,
  original_wo,
  wo_status,
  wo_task_code,
  wo_task_name,
  (etc)...
)
AS
SELECT a.wmm_eqhist_id,
       b.wmt_tag_name,
       c.wmm_wo_code,
       s.name_or_description,
       d.wmm_wotask_id,
       d.wmm_wotask_id,
       (etc)...
FROM   WMM_EQUIPHISTORY a
       LEFT JOIN wmt_tag b ON (a.wmt_tag_id = b.wmt_tag_id)
       LEFT JOIN (
         wmm_workorder c
         INNER JOIN elc_statuses s ON (c.elc_status_id = s.elc_status_id)
       ) ON (a.wmm_wo_id = c.wmm_wo_id)
       LEFT JOIN wmm_woitem d ON (a.wmm_woitem_id = d.wmm_woitem_id)
       (etc)...
WHERE  a.wmm_eqhist_createddate >= DATE '2023-01-01'
WITH READ ONLY
 CONSTRAINT vw_eq_history
/
```

Comment: I went for the inner join. Thank you  MT0